# Define a Collection of types that implement multiple interfaces?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I can define a class of generic types with multiple interfaces like this:

```java
public class MyList<E extends foo & bar & fum> extends ArrayList<E>
```

How can I define a method parameter (or a variable) to be of a `Collection` of base types that implement multiple interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like :

```
public <E extends foo & bar & fum> void test(Collection<E> parameter) {
  ...
}
```

Note that the `E` type here is method-scoped.